# Cannot get the correct user information from the Slack API

Tags: php, curl, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

We're creating a Slack-app, and have gotten most of the things up and running. However, we can't seem to get information about the user. Here is our code so far:

The following code triggers our function. We are sure that the user ID is the correct one, and have tried with several:

```
$uid = getUser("U1234567890");
print_r($uid);
```

This is our function:

```
/* Get User Profile */

public function getUser($userId) {

    $method = "GET";
    $endpoint = "https://slack.com/api/users.info";
    $token = ###;

    $data = array(
        "user" => $userId
    );

    $data = http_build_query($data);

    $response = $this->call_slack_api($token, $method, $endpoint, $data);

    return $response;

}
```

Finally our function to call the API:

```
/* Call the Slack API */

private function call_slack_api($token, $method, $endpoint, $data = "") {

    $curl = curl_init();

    $headers = array(
        "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
    );

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
        CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
    );

    if (isset($data)) {

      $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $data;

    }

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $this->response_code = $info['http_code'];
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
    
}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"user_not_found"}
```

We feel like we've tried everything, and Googled a lot. Anyone who can help us out?

Thank you!

Comment: You are making a GET request, so why are you setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`? You should simply add the query string to the URL.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe - You wont believe how much time we spent on this today :) The solution was simple as usual.